# Why does this integral trick make sense?

Tags: definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I came across an explanation of how to evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{1+\text{tan}x} dx$ which suggested rewriting the integral as $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\text{cos}x}{\text{sin}x + \text{sin}x} dx$.

But those two integrals are not equivalent, so I am not sure why this suggestion is helpful. I initially thought it must just be a typo where one of the sines in the denominator should be a cosine, but the same source suggests a very similar technique for solving a similar integral later, so I am inclined to think that it is not. Can someone help me to understand this?

Edit: Per request, here's the full text:
"Rewrite this integral as $I_1 = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\text{cos}x}{\text{sin}x + \text{sin}x} dx$. Next, consider $I_2 = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\text{sin}x}{\text{sin}x + \text{sin}x} dx$. Add and subtract these two integrals from each other to get integrals you can actually do. For instance, $I_2-I_1 = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\text{sin}x - \text{cos}x}{\text{sin}x + \text{sin}x} dx = \text{ln}(\text{sin}x + \text{cos}x) |_{x = 0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} = 0$. Easily, $I_1 + I_2 = \frac{\pi}{2}$. From here we see that $2I_2 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and then get our answer."

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $(\cos x) / (1 + \sin x)$ for the integrand?

Comment: I mean the source may have a typo and have intended to say that, but that's not what it says.

Comment: No this is a typo by the author, the suggestion is correct though, after rewriting it like that, one can rewrite it's symmetrical form and add both integrals to get the final result as pi/4

Comment: Check the source again. Read the context to see whether it's a typo. [edit] the question to post exactly what it says.

Comment: My running assumption is that the "trick" is to multiply the top and bottom by $\cos x$; this would give you
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos x}{\cos x + \sin x} \, dx
$$

Comment: the second integral does not even converge, whereas the first is equal to $\pi/4$

Comment: @PrincessEev Yeah, I think you're right. If, in both of the integrals in the given solution one of the sines in the denominator should be a cosine, everything works out. I_1 + I_2 is just integrating 1 with the same limits which gives pi/2 as the solution says, and the other can be solved easily with substitution to get an answer of 0, as the solution claims.

Comment: @EthanBolker I added the context, still seems like a typo in the source to me.